# Distribute "Dist" folder with Github

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github, jspm, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

So I'm using Github to host a modified version of Bootstrap for a project (we are compiling just the parts of Bootstrap we need). I'm also using JSPM as the means of which I download the Github project into my local project.

My dilemma is that that when I make a new release, and use JSPM to install the modified version of bootstrap, it brings down a clone of the project, and the dist folder does not contain any files.

Now, if I were to use JSPM to download the main version of bootstrap from Github, I have no problem. So I'm obviously doing something wrong with the release.
**How can I have JSPM just bring down the compiled dist folder from Github?**

The Repo is: https://github.com/Softdocs/bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overridden the files list of the original bootstrap by defining another set of files under the jspm key of the package.json. In particular, you don't list the dist folder in there. So when you install the package via jspm, it installs only files/folders called css, fonts, js. Because the main property refers to a file within the dist folder, you have to include the dist folder too. So just add dist to the list of files defined in jspm attribute of the package.json here: https://github.com/Softdocs/bootstrap/blob/master/package.json#L89

I have tested your package using the following override:

```
"overrides": {
  "github:Softdocs/bootstrap@3.3.5": {
    "main": "./dist/js/npm",
    "files": [
      "dist"
    ]
  }
}
```

And the dist folder was downloaded successfully.

Comment: I've been going off the v4 branch of Bootstrap (the next version, still in alpha). That does get those files included. However, what I want to do is have just the contents of the "dist" brought down (and the module export too) instead of having the folder "dist" brought down. I'm sorry for my lack of package setup on JSPM. I've looked over their documentation, but I'm missing something...

Comment: That did it. I was not quite getting all of it when the jspm documentation talked about a directories.lib file. But I guess that that's what is inside the jspm property of the package.json, since putting it there resolved it. Thanks for the help!